# backbone and mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, model, controller

I have a Backbone project where I have the following model that I want to pass on to .NET for database updating.

```
var myList = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // Default attributes for the todo item.
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            Name: "Default name"
        };
    },



    url: "/my/myList",

    "sync": mySyncFunction,

    // Ensure that each todo created has `title`.
    initialize: function () {
        if (!this.get("Name")) {
            this.set({ "Name": this.defaults.Name });
        }
    }
});
```

Using the following for overriding the sync

```
function mySyncFunction(method, model, options) {
    if (method == 'GET') {

        options.url = model.url;
    }
    else if (method == "create") {

        options.url = model.url+"Post";
    }
    else {

        options.url = model.url;
    }

    Backbone.emulateJSON = true

    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
```

When creating a new item it is using the model.url+"Post" I assumed and the model.get("Name") contains the correct data. The correct section is executed and the entry in the database is created but the Name is empty.

Although when the .NET Controller handles the post the Name no longer contains any data.

My controller code looks like this.

```
   public class myController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult myList()
        {


            List<myCore.myList> l = new List<myCore.myList>();
            l = myCore.myList.ListAll();
            return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }




        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult myListPost(myCore.myList doc)
        {


            doc.AccountGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

            Boolean created = doc.Create();

            return Json(doc);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public ActionResult myListPut(myCore.myList doc)
        {

            myCore.myList doc1 = new myCore.myList();
            doc1.AccountGuid = Guid.Empty;
            doc1.Name = "testPut";
            Boolean created = doc1.Create();

            return Json(doc1);
        }


        [HttpDelete]
        public ActionResult myListDelete(myCore.myList doc)
        {
            //DeleteDoc(id);
            myCore.myList doc1 = new myCore.myList();
            doc1.id = Guid.NewGuid();
            doc1.AccountGuid = Guid.Empty;
            doc1.Name = "testDelete";
            Boolean created = doc1.Create();

            return Json(doc1);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what to do to get the model/class data into the controller.

The myList class looks like this.

```
public class myList
        {
            Guid _id = Guid.Empty;
            String _name = String.Empty;
            Guid _accountGuid = Guid.Empty;
            public Guid id
            {
                get { return _id; }
                set { _id = value; }
            }

            public String Name
            {
                get { return _name; }
                set { _name = value; }
            }

            public Guid AccountGuid
            {
                get { return _accountGuid; }
                set { _accountGuid = value; }
            }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It now looks like it works after removing Backbone.emulateJSON = true

Although I still cant get my delete part to work. It comes up with a 404 error. Only Post and Get works.

It looks like this in the controller.

```
[ActionName("myList")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult myListDelete(myCore.myList doc)
    {

        doc.Name += "-DELETE";


        return Json(doc);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Figured that one out as well.

[ASP.NET Handle PUT/DELETE verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155528/asp-net-handle-put-delete-verbs)

Although i can seem to pass any model or paramters along with it on order to delete the correct entry in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Change your defaults to

```
defaults: {
     Name: "Default name"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't make any difference though. I can see that my post contains model=%7B%22Name%22%3A%22England%22%7D and if i in my controller request model and deserializes it then I can convert it to my object, but as I have understood it, I wouldn't have to do it that way.